# Using async/await still returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I asked recently about the asynchronous in javascript, [request-promise module returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53367823/request-promise-module-returns-undefined). I quite understand it after someone gave the same SO question which is the [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). I learned a lot which helps me to how properly request an api. But now I encounter the same problem even though I'm using `async/await` already. I put comments where I'm getting an `undefined`.

```
const request = require('request');
const rp = require('request-promise');

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

const CONNECTION_STRING = process.env.DB;
const dbName = 'fcc';
const connectionOption = { useNewUrlParser: true };

function StockHandler() {

  this.latestWithoutLike = async function(ticker, multipleStock, callback) {
    if (!multipleStock) {
      console.log('Single stock');
      let lastPrice = await getLastPrice(ticker);

      if (typeof lastPrice === 'string') {
        getLikes(ticker, false, (data) => {

          let stockData = {
            stock: data.stock,
            price: lastPrice,
            likes: data.likes
          }

          return callback({ stockData: stockData });
        });
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Multiple stock');
      let firstStockLastPrice = await getLastPrice(ticker[0]);
      let secondStockLastPrice = await getLastPrice(ticker[1]);

      if (typeof firstStockLastPrice === 'string' && typeof secondStockLastPrice === 'string') {
        let firstStockLikes = await getLikes(ticker[0], false, (data) => { return data; });
        let secondStockLikes = await getLikes(ticker[1], false, (data) => { return data; });

        console.log(firstStockLikes); // <--- undefined
        console.log(secondStockLikes); // <--- undefined
      }

    } 
  };

  this.latestWithLike = async function(ticker, multipleStock, callback) {
    if (!multipleStock) {
      console.log('Single stock');
      let lastPrice = await getLastPrice(ticker);
      console.log(lastPrice);
      if (typeof lastPrice === 'string') {
        getLikes(ticker, true, (data) => {

          let stockData = {
            stock: data.stock,
            price: lastPrice,
            likes: data.likes + 1
          }

          return callback({ stockData: stockData });
        });
      }

    } else {
      console.log('Multiple stock');
      let firstStockLastPrice = await getLastPrice(ticker[0]);
      let secondStockLastPrice = await getLastPrice(ticker[1]);
      console.log(firstStockLastPrice);
      console.log(secondStockLastPrice);
    }
  };  

}

function getLastPrice(ticker) {
  let options = {
    uri:  `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=${ticker}&interval=1min&apikey=${process.env.ALPHA_KEY}`,
    method: 'GET',
    json: true
  }

  return rp(options)
    .then(function(parsedBody){
      let latestStockTradeTime = Object.keys(parsedBody[Object.keys(parsedBody)[1]])[0];
      let closingPrice = parsedBody[Object.keys(parsedBody)[1]][latestStockTradeTime]['4. close'];
      return closingPrice;
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      return error;
    })
}

function getLikes(ticker, likeStatus, callback) {
  MongoClient.connect(CONNECTION_STRING, connectionOption, (err, client) => {

    if (err) callback(err);

    const db = client.db(dbName);
    const collection = db.collection('stock');

    if (!likeStatus) {
      try {
        collection.findOne(
          { stock: ticker.toUpperCase() },
          { upsert: true },
          (err, result) => {
            if (result === null) {
              collection.insertOne(
                { stock: ticker.toUpperCase(), likes: 0 },
                { upsert: true },
                (err, result) => {
                  return callback(result.ops[0]);
                }
              ); 
            } else {
                return callback(result);
            }
          }
        );
      } catch (e) {
          return callback({ error: e });
      }  
    } 
    else {
      try {
        collection.findOneAndUpdate(
          { stock: ticker.toUpperCase() },
          { $inc : { likes: 1 } },
          { upsert: true, new: true },
          (err, data) => {
            return callback(data.value);
          }
        );
      } catch (e) {
          return callback({ error: e });
      }
    }

  });
};

module.exports = StockHandler;
```

Comment: If you want to use `async/await` then `getLikes()` needs to return a promise.

Comment: What are the other options just in case I don't want to use `async/await` ?

Comment: This is a lot of code to review. Basically, what @MarkMeyer said: just like a synchronous function, a function using async/await should return a value if you need to chain it, the difference being an `async function()` wraps its return value (or error) in a Promise.

Comment: Does it mean that any function called inside the `async function()` needs to use `await`? Because I'm still confuse especially when I remove the `await` on that two I'm still getting `undefined`.

Answer (score 11):

If you're defining [a function with asynchronous behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), you can use `async/await` or Promise chaining. Inside an async function, you can use `await` or chain `.then()` to wait for asynchronous responses. Your function returns a Promise with the resolved value or error to its callers.

```
async function getLikes() {
  const likes = await db.get('myLikes'); // this db method returns a Promise
  // ...
  return likes; // will return a Promise resolving likes from db or an error if there is one
}

async function logLikes() {
  const result = await getLikes();
  console.log(result);
}
```

If you're consuming an asynchronous function and do not await or chain the response like in this example...

```
async function getLikes() {
  const likes = db.get('myLikes'); // uh oh, this is asynchronous
  // ...
  return likes;
}
```

... the thread can move on before the return value is assigned to `like`. That may be where you're seeing `undefined` issues.